# gatling jms-Nosuchmethoderror

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, gatling

I installed ActiveMQ in my local machine. I want to test it using Gatling. I created one simulation class to test my JMS. But I am getting error shown below.

**Here is My Code:**

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.jms.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import javax.jms._
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory


class JmsTest extends  Simulation{
    val jmsConfig = jms
    .connectionFactoryName("connectionFactory")
    .url("tcp://localhost:61616")
    .credentials("admin", "admin")
    .contextFactory(classOf[org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory].getName)
    .listenerCount(1)

      val scn = scenario("JMS DSL test").repeat(1) {
        exec(jms("req reply testing")
          .reqreply
          .queue("MyQueue")
          .replyQueue("MyTopic")
          .textMessage("Hello this is Naveen")
        )
      }
      setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
        .protocols(jmsConfig)       
    }
```

**I created jndi.properties file with following code.**

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = vm://localhost
connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory
queue.MyQueue = TestJms1
topic.MyTopic = TestJms1
```

**The error which I am getting is:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.gatling.jms.Predef$.jms()Lio/gatling/jms/protocol/JmsProtocolBuilderBase$;
        at computerdatabase.JmsTest.<init>(JmsTest.scala:14)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.io$gatling$app$Gatling$$$anonfun$1(Gatling.scala:41)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.run(Gatling.scala:92)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.runIfNecessary(Gatling.scala:75)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.start(Gatling.scala:65)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:57)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```